# The sql query return different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

These are my 2 queries,when executed they return different results one is subquery'd and other dne using joins.

Please guide me deciding on the better one,this need to be generic sql (As I dont know clients RDBMS)

-- Gives correct results

```
select count(*) from cardh
where email_id isnull 
and to_date(dt,'YYYYMMDD') < (SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH',getdate()) + INTERVAL '4 MONTH - 1 day')::date)    
and  sts = (SELECT ref_id                                                                       
FROM ref
WHERE typ = 'ActS'                                                                     
AND   desc LIKE 'Act%')
```

and the second query  --incorrect results

```
select count(*) from cardh a inner join ref b on b.ref_id=a.sts
where a.email_id isnull 
and to_date(a.dt,'YYYYMMDD') < (SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH',getdate()) + INTERVAL '4 MONTH - 1 day')::date)
and b.typ = 'Acts'  AND   b.desc LIKE 'Act%'
```

I messed up somewhere in second one I'm using `postgres`

Comment: Which one produces the **correct** results?

Comment: "isnull" should probably be "is null"

Comment: the two query doesn't seems same...In the second one you have 'Act%' instead of 'Acte%' as in the first query...and also in typ = 'ActS'  ..

Comment: I hope this work in postgresql and not in sql server.

Comment: Proper schema information would be very helpful here...

Comment: @Liath : that did not make any difference thanks.

Comment: @Riad : its just a typo thnaks.

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna You fixed the first typo pointed out, but you missed that in Query 1 you have `WHERE typ = 'ActS'` and in Query 2 you have `AND b.typ = 'Acts'`. Postgres is case sensitive, so it will make a difference in the results. Besides that, the two statements appears to be equal.